# Why am I getting a UndefinedUnitError using pint & pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pint

Following along with the documentation of pint-pandas and pint as best I could, I have an implementation which does not seem to want to work.
This reproduces my UndefinedUnitError.

```
import pint
import pint_pandas
ureg = UnitRegistry()
ureg.load_definitions('pint_unit_definitions.txt')
pint.set_application_registry(ureg)


df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,6],[1,3,4]], dtype='pint[bpm]' )
```

My pint_unit_definitions.txt file looks like this:

```
minute = 60 * second = min
beats_per_minute = beat / minute = bpm
hertz = counts / second = hz
beat = [heart_beats] = b
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Savage kindly answered this question for me on [github](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint-pandas/issues/79). It turns out I was missing a line. It works as below:

```
import pint
import pint_pandas
ureg = UnitRegistry()
ureg.load_definitions('pint_unit_definitions.txt')
pint.set_application_registry(ureg)
pint_pandas.PintType.ureg = ureg


df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,6],[1,3,4]], dtype='pint[bpm]' )
```